# How to refer to an instance that both extends and implements?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface

Let's say I have an abstract class, an extending class, and an interface like this:

```
public abstract class SuperClass {
    ...
    public void foo() {...}
    ...
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass implements MyInterface {...}

public interface MyInterface {
    public void bar();
}
```

Note that I have a few subclasses of SuperClass implementing MyInterface, but not all of them.
Also let's say, I have another class with a constructor like this:

```
public class AnotherClass {
    private SuperClass sc;
    public AnotherClass(SuperClass superclass) {
        sc = superclass;
    }
    ...
}
```

My question now is, how would I be able to ensure that the given object in the constructor also implements MyInterface? I would need the object `sc` to be able to run both methods `foo()` and `bar()`. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: by defining it as `SubClass` or by casting it.

Comment: Make SuperClass implement your interface

Comment: Defining it as `SubClass` wouldn't make sense, as I need all subclasses implementing `MyInterface` to fit in the constructor. I could give casting a try though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could introduce another class to the hierachy:

```
public class NonImplementingSubClass extends SuperClass {...}

public class ImplementingSubClass extends SuperClass implements MyInterface {...}
```

All your subclasses that should implement your interface, will then extend `ImplementingSubClass`

```
public class SubClass extends ImplementingSubClass {...}

public class AnotherClass {
    private ImplementingSubClass sc;
    public AnotherClass(ImplementingSubClass superclass) {
        sc = superclass;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `generics` with intersection types,

```
public class AnotherClass<T extends SuperClass & MyInterface> {
private T sc;
public AnotherClass(T superclass) {
    sc = superclass;
}
void fn(){
 // use both methods
 sc.foo();
 sc.bar();
}
...
}
```

Now, `AnotherClass` will only allow types that are `SuperClass` and implement `MyInterface`.

Comment: I like this, but making the class generic seems unfortunate. How about, instead of having a field ```T```  have 2 fields, one of type ```SuperClass``` and one of type ```MyInterface```, and just store the reference twice?

Comment: @JornVernee Why is it unfortunate? I don't see why generics can cause any harm

Comment: Not a bad idea, but I guess it would get kinda messy once I need to return the object to a different class and accessing the methods from there on...

Comment: It adds complexity e.g. when declaring variables: ```AnotherClass<SomeType>```. While this is not really needed. ```AnotherClass``` does not need to know the specific type being passed, only that it extends both ```SuperClass``` and ```MyInterface```.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class SuperClass implements MyInterface {
    ...
    public void foo() {...}
    ...
}

public class SubClass extends SuperClass{}

public interface MyInterface {
    public void bar();
}
```